# Spring method with React front

Tags: reactjs, spring, fetch

Hi i'm trying to create small project with React Front and Spring Java backend.
Let's say in Spring Controller class i have a method:

```
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000/")
@GetMapping("/something")
public void printSomething()
{
    System.out.println("examplePhrase");
}
```

In React i have a form with button that invoke method 'handleSpring' looks like:

```
    handleSpring = e =>
{
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Method started");
  const SpringAPI = `http://localhost:8080/something`

  fetch(SpringAPI, {})
  .then(response => console.log("method works"))
  .catch(err => console.log("method failed"))
}
```

When i run both application and go to "localhost:8080/something" i have a message in Intellij console "examplePhrase" so Spring method works. When i'm going to "localhost:3000", i have my form made by React. But when i right-click on this site, choose "inspect" -> "console" in browser menu, and next press form button i have an error:

> method started
> localhost/:1 Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/something' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
> App.js:50 GET http://localhost:8080/something net::ERR_FAILED
> App.js:50 method failed

I tried to add "no cors" to fetch but it doesn't change anything. Can anybody tell me how i could fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trailing slash in cors origin is causing the error.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000") // no slash at end in origin.
```

Hope this fixes your issue.

Comment: Maybe i shouldn't admit, but I struggled with this all evening. Huge thanks. :D